# How to get new questions continuously?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am a beginner with the Stack Exchange API.  I would like to get a continuous stream of new questions on Stack Overflow so that I can do some number crunching with it.

Do I have to periodically query the `/questions` endpoint with a time window to get newer questions or is there another publish/subscribe way of achieving this so that I receive the newer questions rather than polling for them?

Comment: Nearly duplicate:  http://stackapps.com/questions/3750/is-there-a-way-or-app-to-get-realtime-updates-of-new-questions-with-a-given-ta

Answer (score 5):

Probably the most cost-effective way *is* to poll `/questions` every minute or two.  (Results are cached so, polling more than once a minute *probably* won't do anything but chew up your quota.)

Related: [Provide a streaming API instead of forcing API users to poll](https://stackapps.com/questions/2898/provide-a-streaming-api-instead-of-forcing-api-users-to-poll)

Alternatives:

- You can get real-time notifications by hooking into one of [the undocumented WebSockets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343/how-do-the-stack-exchange-websockets-work-what-are-all-the-options-you-can-send).  Note that the only endpoint that still seems to work is the `155-questions-active` one.  I can no longer get the Stack Overflow specific endpoints to work on my current setup.
  Since it is *active* questions, rather than *newest*, you will need to separately track which questions are really new.
  Also, `155` is network wide, so you would need to check each response to see if it is for Stack Overflow.
- [Hook-into/Scrape the Stack Exchange *real-time* page](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) and ignore all the questions from sites you are not interested in.  <sub>Note that I *suspect* that this page misses questions, but have no evidence of that.</sub>
  Also, this information is essentially the same as for the `155-questions-active` WebSocket endpoint.
- Poll one of [the RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its).  This works best if you are interested only in specific tags.
- Poll [the /events route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events) and filter for questions. This is not subject to 60-second caching.

But the API is designed for automated access in ["close enough" to real time](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle). I recommend that you use it and just poll one of the `/questions` routes (or `/search`, etc.).